# XSLT syntax explanation required

Tags: xml, xslt

Can someone explain the below syntax of XSL

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and add the 2 lines of code in the question instead of attaching them as an image. It will be helpful for those providing answers to the question and reduce the downvotes for the question.

Answer (score 1):

`match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]"`

`@*` - the template matches all attribute nodes

`node()[XXX]` - the template matches elements, text nodes, comments, and processing instructions, provided that the predicate XXX is true

`self::*` - if the context node is an element, this selects the element, otherwise it selects nothing

`not(self::*)` - is true if `self::*` selects nothing, that is, if the context node is not an element.

So the code matches all attributes, text nodes, comments, and processing instructions

It could also be written

`match="@* | text() | comment() | processing-instruction()"`

The next line

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}"/>
```

Creates an element whose name is the same as the local name of the context item. This is fine if the context item is an attribute or processing instruction, but it will cause a dynamic error if the context item is a comment or text node, because those nodes have no local-name.

So the code is buggy: it doesn't make sense to write a template rule that matches comments and text nodes and then fails if it encounters one.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating elements with all node() names and attributes not remaining elements:

1. All attributes will be crated as elements.
2. All nodes will create as elements

**Note:** you are not matching elemetns